# UPDATE query to Remove Character from right in a colunm

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Value is  14.88 BTD

I want just 14.88

Which means i want to remove last three characters. using a single UPDATE. Thanks in advance

Comment: Would you want last 4 characters to address the space before BTD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will update all values, in every row

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = SUBSTRING(column_name , 0, LENGTH(column_name ) - 3))
```

Comment: UPDATE POS SET PurchasePrice = SUBSTRING(PurchasePrice , 0, LENGTH(PurchasePrice ) - 3)
It's Working .....@lffo

Comment: I would possibly include WHERE PurchasePrice like '%BDT' to prevent accidentally removing on rows that don't match your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

update #tt set column_name=                 SUBSTRING(column_name,CHARINDEX('*',column_name)+1,LEN(column_name)-4)

Comment: UPDATE table_name SET column_name = SUBSTRING(column_name , 0, LENGTH(column_name ) - 3))
I try like this and it's working @DBname